# Is if statement correct?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c

```
if(temperature < baselineTemp)else{
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
}else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+2 && temperature < baselineTemp+4){
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH)
  digitalWrite(3, LOW)
  digitalWrite(4, LOW)
}else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+4 && temperature < baselineTemp+6){
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH)
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH)
  digitalWrite(4, LOW)
}else if(temperature >= baselineTemp+6){
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH)
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH)
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the first lines should be:

```
if(temperature < baselineTemp) {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
```

Thus the `else` should be removed; after the first `if` and later `else` or `else if` conditions, statements can be placed.

Next time align your code by selecting it and select ctrl-K.

Also, your code can be much more simplified.

Hence the following (reverse engineered) requirements:

- pin 2 is HIGH when temperature >= baselineTemp + 2, else LOW
- pin 3 is HIGH when temperature >= baselineTemp + 4, else LOW
- pin 4 is HIGH when temperature >= baselineTemp + 4, else LOW

So your entire code can be written as:

```
digitalWrite(2, temperature >= baselineTemp + 2 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(3, temperature >= baselineTemp + 4 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(4, temperature >= baselineTemp + 6 ? HIGH : LOW);
```